# Missing documents in Windows 10 following upgrade

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I just upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 7 and cannot locate my Word or Excel files, Also my contacts are missing- where did they go?

I tried opening `Documents`, but there is nothing in that location

Comment: Have you tried using Windows' search yet?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of upgrade you performed. Check the following areas for your files:

1. C:\Windows.old folder
2. Network/
3. My Computer > C:\ > pc > users > public

If you selected "Wipe all files and Data" during the upgrade however, there is a good possibility that all personal files have been deleted.